# Using authenticated proxy with apache http client 4.3.6

Tags: apache, http, authentication, proxy

Can someone point me to authoritative example that demonstrates use of Proxy with authentication.

My searches reveal varied examples not necessarily using ver. 4.3.6 and hence the confusion.

I encountered two approaches as following. I prefer NOT to set the proxy and credentials for every request and hence wondering whats the best practice here? Also I have to make sure this works for Basic, Digest and NTLM schemes.

Approach 1:

```
// Create client and set credential provider
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build();
// Every request is set the with proxy settings
RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setProxy(proxy)
            .build();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("/");
httpget.setConfig(config);
```

Approach 2:

```
HttpHost proxyHost = new HttpHost(proxyServer, proxyPort);
DefaultProxyRoutePlanner routePlanner = new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxyHost);

HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClients.custom()
            .setConnectionManager(connectionManager);
clientBuilder.setRoutePlanner(routePlanner);

client = clientBuilder.build();

// Where and how to set credentials as best practice ?
```

I am sure to get some heckling for this one but so far I have wondered too much hence asking some help.
thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Ok Here is what I ended up doing and solves the use case.

```
// Method that returns HTTP Client that can be re-used for various GET/POST/... calls
static CloseableHttpClient makeHttpClient(...) throws IOException {

    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
    // Default MAX connections per route
    connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(...);
    // MAX total connections
    connectionManager.setMaxTotal(...);

    HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClients.custom()
            .setConnectionManager(connectionManager);
    // Set proxy if needed
    HttpHost proxyHost = new HttpHost(theProxyServer, port);
   DefaultProxyRoutePlanner routePlanner = new  DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxyHost);
   clientBuilder.setRoutePlanner(routePlanner);

   // Select and configure the properties you are interested in
   RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
                    .setProxy(proxyHost)
                    .setRedirectsEnabled(true)
                    .setMaxRedirects(5)
                    .setConnectTimeout(100 * 1000)
                    .setConnectionRequestTimeout(300 * 1000)
                    .setSocketTimeout(300 * 1000)
                    .build();

   // set proxy authentication as needed
   CredentialsProvider credentialProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
   // set NTLM/basic/digest credentials
   credentialProvider.setCredentials(...)
   ....

   clientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialProvider);
   clientBuilder.setDefaultRequestConfig(config);

   // Now build and return the client
   return clientBuilder.build();
}
```

Now in other places use this client to perform HTTP operations.

```
// get HTTP client
makeHttpClient(...)
// get payload 
HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(url);
postMethod.setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, CONTENT_TYPE_JSON);
postMethod.setEntity(payload);

try {
        response = client.execute(postMethod);
        ...
} catch(...) { ... }
```

This helps to create a HTTP client with all desired characteristics that can be re-used for various HTTP operations in different places.